# C# NumericUpDown.OnValueChanged, how it was changed?

Tags: c#, .net, numericupdown, eventargs

I would like to ask how to make custom EventArgs for existing event handler.

Lets say, that I have `NumericUpDown numericUpDown` control and I want handler for its `OnValueChanged` event. Double clicking to `ValueChanged` in visual studio makes snippet like this

```
private void numericUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

However, I'd like to know how it was changed (like +5, -4.7), but plain `EventArgs` does not have this information. Maybe `Decimal change = Value - Decimal.Parse(Text)` would do the trick (because of delayed text change), but that's ugly way and may not work every single time.

I guess I should make my own EventArgs like this

```
class ValueChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Decimal Change { get; set; }
}
```

and then somehow override `NumericUpDown.OnValueChanged` event to generate my EventArgs with proper information.

Comment: Could you just store the previous value of the control and then compare it to the current value in the event handler?

Comment: @APerson If I had more controls of this type using same event handler, I would have to store all possible previous values during whole runtime.

Comment: There is no built-in storage of previous content. If you need to track that to calculate value changes, you'll need to store it yourself.

Comment: @Zereges Then make a `Dictionary` mapping `NumericUpDown`s to the values they formerly held.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be much easier to just tag the last value.

```
    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        NumericUpDown o = (NumericUpDown)sender;
        int thisValue = (int) o.Value;
        int lastValue = (o.Tag == null) ? 0 : (int) o.Tag;
        o.Tag = thisValue;
        MessageBox.Show("delta = " + (thisValue - lastValue));
    }
```

Comment: Well, I didn't think about using tag for this. This could do the trick, I'll probably use it. However, if I wanted to use custom event args, how would I do that?

Comment: Just small warning for anyone trying to do the same. `(int) o.Tag` throws `InvalidCastException`, so use rather `int.Parse(o.Tag.ToString())` or `Convert.ToInt32(o.Tag)`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create your own numeric up down control that extends the .net version, define a delegate type for your event and then hide the base controls event property.

Delegate:

```
public delegate void MyOnValueChangedEvent(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args);
```

Event Args Class:

```
class ValueChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Decimal Change { get; set; }
}
```

New NumericUpDown class, hide the inherited event with 'new':

```
public class MyNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
{
    public new event MyOnValueChangedEvent OnValueChanged;
}
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16(v=vs.110).aspx) for instructions on how to raise your custom event, and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) for additional information on event handling.